# use single js file for multiple views without breaking on undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single js file for my editting backend. The problem is that for view A I only need a handful of methods and for view B I need another set but I never need any methods on **both** pages.

I decided to put all the jquery for both views in a single file but it breaks when a selector is not available and the rest of the jquery isn't parsed anymore. This causes the page to be unusable.

Is there a way to use a single jquery file, containing all methods for all views even if there are undefined function exceptions?

```
$("#mal_search").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/mal/search",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            // In case a single result is returned we put the
            // data object into an array otherwise select2 will
            // not be able to read the object
            if (!$.isArray(data)) {
                data = [data];
            }
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});

///////////////////////////////////
// The following doesn't work if the above method throws a is not a function exception
$('#filename-url-container').on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
    var formGroup = $('#filename-url-container > :first-child').first().clone(true);
    formGroup.find('input').val('');   // erase values
    $('#filename-url-container').append(formGroup);
    formGroup.closest('button.btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
});
```

Comment: Make your code account for the element not being available, that way no errors are thrown and it doesn't cause the rest of the javascript from executing.

Comment: jQuery by default can always handle a selector not being found. You'll have to show your code if you want a solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't see how your code has anything to do with hoisting.

Comment: @Juhana then I have misunderstood the explanation. Anyway, code is coming up.

Comment: just wrap a function around each chunk so that nobody ever looks for something that's missing at run-time. ex: `function setupA(){ ...} function setupB(){ ... }` even better would be to break it into A,B, and ALL.

Answer (score -1):

hoisting is when you use a function/variable before it is defined, as it is described in your link. Hoisting isn't a problem per-se but makes your code leak global variables and is hard for other developers to read. So you shouldn't do it, "but you could"

regarding the splitting up. as you know which functions will be used on page1 and which ones on page2, put them in a file page1.js and page2.js and load them on the pages. You also can put them all into one single file and have a startPage1 function and a startPage2 function which starts the pages as you want them to. Sadly, without more code, I am not able to help you